# Entity Framework Core does not have access to system tables

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016

I'm using EF Core to access CDC tables within system tables in SQL Server, but command `ef scaffold` does not find the tables. I do access tables out of system tables successfully.

I've tried to grant table to dbo owner, without success.

**Stack**

- SQL Server 2016
- EF Core 3.1

Comment: Not sure you can use the CDC tables directly, and I would probably recommend against it since they can change between SQL Server versions. If you really want to use them, you could create some views over the top of them and use them instead.

Comment: Actually it's a very specific scenario. The view worked, I read fields from cdc table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the CDC tables directly, and I would probably recommend against it since they can change between SQL Server versions.

If you really want to use them, you could create one or more views over the top of the CDC tables and use them instead. That way EF will pick them up and they are somewhat future proof if the tables change since you only need to change the views instead of fix and recompile your code.